# If a mail server automatically deletes old messages and I use IMAP on my devices, will I lose those emails?

Tags: email, imap

My father's work email is configured to use POP. The problem is that he receives tons of spam and he is annoyed to delete it twice (hundreds of spam mail everyday).

I was wondering to configure it in IMAP but my fear is that he could lose emails because server auto-deletes mail older the XX days.

Is there a way to prevent losing emails autoremoved from server while using IMAP?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the differences between the IMAP and POP protocols. When your computer connects to an POP server, it transfers the available messages from the incoming mailbox to you client computer. After the completion of this transfer, the messages are deleted from the incoming mailbox located on the server. When connecting to the E-Mail server using IMAP, your E-Mail folders located on the server will be attached to your local computer in nearly in the same manner as when mounting folders on a remote machine. The main difference is that these folders contain messages, not files.

As mentioned in the previous message, it's very important to disable the POP account when you switch to the IMAP protocol on THE SAME server. Please, do not delete the POP account and its folders, simply disable it so that no connections are made to the server using POP.

When using IMAP, you have the full control on every message. You can move, copy, delete as usual when using folders containing data. Please note that local options will define what "delete" will do. The usual action is to move messages to your Trash folder. Please verify what is set at your site.

Many E-Mail servers offer the POP and the IMAP protocols at the same time. Please remember the differences and remember that the incoming mailbox is exactly the same in this case. When POP has transferred a message from the server to the client, it will be removed from the incoming mailbox on the server. Then, you will not longer see it when connection to the same server using IMAP. This is the reason why you should not use both protocols on the same server at the same time.

If your POP and IMAP accounts for the same server are on the same computer at your site, you are in luck. The messages you could not find on your incoming mailbox of your IMAP account will probably be in the incoming mailbox of your POP account. Your client software will probably allow you to move these messages to the other incoming mailbox on the other account. If you have used POP on different client computers, using the same account on the same server, you will find the messages on your different client computers. Please remember: If you want to work from different clients, then use IMAP, not POP.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should worry.

I have never encountered an IMAP mailserver that automatically deletes emails. If it did it would be quite the scandal, for IMAP is intended for accessing a central mail archive from multiple locations.

However, make sure to disable all POP accounts after switching to IMAP.

Comment: There are at least two scenarios how messages could get deleted automatically on an Exchange server: 1. Auto-archiving: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AutoArchive-settings-explained-444BD6AA-06D0-4D8F-9D84-903163439114 and 2. Retention policy: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/messaging-records-management/default-retention-policy